# Can't find the module that I downloaded for python 3.7

Tags: module, pip, python-3.7

Hi I just downloaded the module docx using pip, I have a mac so I used the terminal, here is what I entered in terminal

```
pip install python-docx
```

I have python 3.7 installed and I am using PyCharm's latest version but I can't find the module and when I try to import it PyCharm doesn't recognize it.
The error PyCharm gives me is "No module named docx"

p.s. of you know how to install numpy or know where can I find the instructions to download numpy it would make my day.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us the error the Pycharm gives you.
on other hand to download numpy `pip install numpy` or check the [link](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)

Comment: There, I already put it in the question. Anyways, the error it gives me is "No module named docx"

Comment: I once had that issue and it was because
you have 2 versions of python and you installed the module on one and running your app on another.
Try do pip install **sudo pip install --pre python-docx** and  then **sudo pip3 install --pre python-docx**